# Iframe display blank after update Chrome from version 114 to 115

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-chrome, iframe

I have updated my Chrome from version 114 to 115. After this, all of iframe on my web application turns to blank when open.
Here's the way I call iframe:

```
<div class="modal fade loadIframe">
    <iframe id="frame-top-dt" src="BASE_PATH/xxx.php?id=ID" width="100%" style="border:0px;height: 100%;"></iframe>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#click-on-me').click(function() {
        $(".loadIframe").css("display", "block");
    })
</script>
```

Request to file .php hasn't been executed, and process stops right after this.

[Request error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEBNF.png)

Iframe just show blank page, no data display as expected.
Has anyone faced this issue?

Thanks.

I tried to use setTimeout on javascript, but it's still error

Comment: check your console for a possible ```CORS``` error

Comment: is there any response or response headers? I have no such issues with iframes

Comment: I tried to add header to avoid CORS, but it's still not working, my response header is empty. Btw, this issue has just happened when I update Chrome to version 115.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the plain vanilla way? Just write

```
<iframe id="frame-top-dt" src="BASE_PATH/xxx.php?id=ID" width="100%" style="border: 0px; height: 100%;"></iframe>
```

and see if it works.

Or check if `BASE_PATH/xxx.php?id=ID` is valid.
Or replace the `src` value with it's actual value.

Comment: I tried but it's still happening :(

Comment: If so, try echoing `BASE_PATH/xxx.php?id=ID` and see if it works.